# Using Neo4j Cypher to obtain the longest path without the first or last node

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a forest of nodes and relationships. Similar to the following:

N1-sends->N2-sends->N3-sends->N4

N5-sends->N6-sends->N7-sends->N8

N9-sends->N10-sends->N11-sends->N12-sends->N13

I want to write a Cypher query that returns the 3 paths, without the first or last item. The nodes that are NOT at the beginning or end of the paths already have a property("middle", "true"), so that makes it easier.

A problem that I have encountered is that Cypher returns the path and every SUBSET of the path as well. For example it returns n10->n11-> and n11->n2, and n10->n11->n12, .... which is not what I want.

Instead I just want the results to be an array of 3, where inside each I have:

n2->n3

n6->n7

n10->n11->n12

and thats it.

The queries that I have came up with are:  (first one has syntax errors):

```
START n=node(*) MATCH p=()-[*]->i-[*]->() WHERE has(i.middle) 
WITH COLLECT(p) AS pa, MAX(length(p)) AS maxLength, NODES(p) AS pn
FILTER(path IN pa WHERE length(path)=maxLength) AS longestPaths 
RETURN DISTINCT FILTER(x IN longestPaths WHERE exists(x.middle))
```

and

```
START n=node(*) MATCH p=()-[*]->i-[*]->() 
WHERE has(i.middle)  
RETURN DISTINCT filter(x IN NODES(p) WHERE exists(x.middle)) as O
```

The second one returns the paths without the first and last node, but it returns duplicated nodes, because it returns subsets of path as well..

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This might do what you want:

```
MATCH (n)-[:sends*]->(m)
WHERE NOT ( ()-[:sends]->(n) OR (m)-[:sends]->() )
RETURN NODES(p)[1..-1] AS middleNodes;
```

The `WHERE` clause eliminates sub-paths (i.e., paths that are part of a longer path). The `NODES(p)[1..-1]` syntax returns the second through next-to-last nodes in each path.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this today. 
Does this work with paths longer than 4 nodes? meaning does the WHERE clause remove subsets that are not the longest.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The `WHERE` clause eliminates all paths that are part of a longer path.

Comment: I mean does the WHERE clause remove only subsets of size 2 nodes or any size subset. From the above code you provided I thought (m)-[:sends]->()  means only subsets of size 2.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause eliminates 2 kinds of paths: (a) paths where `n` has another node "before" it, and (b) paths where `m` has another node "after" it. There can be any number of nodes in between `n` and `m`, so the resulting paths can be of any length (>=1, in this query).